# Define specific encoding when I use unload informix sentence

Tags: informix

this is my conflict: I am using UNLOAD sentence from informix db to export 400 tables from a DB, but some (not all) of this tables are saved with Western-1252 encoding in .csv files, I want to ensure sentence UNLOAD download this csv files with UTF-8 encoding, something like: " unload to myfile.csv, delimiter:'|', encoding:'UTF-8', select ....

Is that posible ?
thanks.

Comment: Maybe research over on DBA SE. https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure to understand your first statement "... I am using UNLOAD sentence from informix db to export 400 tables from a DB, but some (not all) of this tables are saved with Western-1252 encoding in .csv files ..."

The encoding of the unload format ('csv' in your case) is determined by the last part of the CLIENT_LOCALE environment variable. 
If you want the unload to be in UTF8, just set something like CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8.
The Informix GLS library will perform a codeset conversion between the codeset of your database (specified by DB_LOCALE) and the codeset you set in your CLIENT_LOCALE.

All files will have the same encoding.

Comment: Hi Jsagrera, thanks for your comment... I was doing this task by mean of a telnet prompt .. I have no access to ENVIRONMENT variables, and it´s hard I can configure that client_locale variable, I will try other option. maybe a non-automatic solution

Comment: If you are doing a telnet to the server, you will have a shell (prompt) from where you are running the dbaccess/isql program to run the UNLOAD SQL statement. Just prefix the dbaccess with "CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.utf8" which will set the environment for that process. For example, "CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.utf8 dbaccess mydb unload.sql".

Another option would be to have the CLIENT_LOCALE variable set to UTF8 in your informix environment configuration file (either globally '$INFORMIXDIR/etc/informix.rc' or just for your user ($HOME/.informix).

Comment: **Jsagrera** thanks for your suggestion/solution
updating environment variable ...
:D :D :D

Comment: It will help if you can tell us which Informix version you are using. I dont recall seeing an UNLOAD Informix SQL extension supporting an encoding option. There are other Informix load/unload Informix utilities like DBLOAD and HPL that might support it, or if possible, ask the DBA if he/she can provide you with the unload file with encoding you are seeking.